# Password protection with .htaccess, switch variable on / off

Tags: php, .htaccess, passwords, authorization, http-status-code-401

**Question:** I've got a `config.php` file in my cms with some define's. I want to have a flag in my `config.php`:

```
define('PROTECTED', true);
```

And than protect my page directory using `htaccess`, and `htpasswd` only if `PROTECTED`.

What should be great is to have user and pass also stored in `config.php`:

```
define('PROTECTED', true);
define('PROTECTED_USER', 'user');
define('PROTECTED_PASS', 'pass');
```

And than transfer them into `htpasswd` or `htaccess` somehow... As a matter of fact, the `config.php` is a page config, and password protection is of course a page config, so they should be in the same place.

**Rejected solution:** I've come with an idea, to implement (below a snippet of the most simpliest code possible only to sketch the idea) 401 in my..., let's name it `index.php`:

```
index.php:  

// Config file
require_once("config.php"); 

// Password protected?
$user = (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : "");
$pass = (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : "");

if (!PROTECTED || (PROTECTED && $user == PROTECTED_USER && $pass == PROTECTED_PASS)) {
    // RenderPage
}
else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authorisation required"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
}
```

But it only blocks `index.php` and "page engine", and not for example images stored in `/layout/images/top_secret.jpg`, and if someone knows the path, the file isn't protected.

Of course, U can redirect ALL traffic to `index.php` using `.htaccess`, and implement a special gate for `jpg`, `css` and other normal files. It should read the header of the file, set header, and use `file_put_contents`. But this is not memory efficient, and personally I think it is a stupid solution :). It is better to leave it outside `config.php`, than in that way...

Thx for Your time :).

Comment: I have done a really great amount of searching, and still no solution obtained :(. Every help will be much appreciated :).